# How to replace line in file below text pattern

Tags: shell, sed

In a shell script (Almquist shell) I need to replace the next line **after** a comment text pattern.

```
# specific comment line
if [ -d "/home/somewhere" ];then
```

I cannot sed-change the line directly as the *if [ -d*... line may appear more then once in that file and I only need to change the one after the comment.
Can this be done with sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^# specific comment line$/{n;s/.*/foo/}' file
```

Output:

```
# specific comment line
foo
```

Comment: add the `;` - e.g. `...{n;s/.*/foo/;}'` and will work on OS X (non GNU) sed too.. ;)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I have some variable text after '# specific comment line'. Removing the $ as a delimiter works for lines with more text after my initial comment text.